# Missing Position Field Type in Matrix (Craft 3)

Tags: craft3, fieldtypes, position

Anyone know how to get the **`Position`** field type to show up in Craft 3 (RC)?

I have a `Matrix` field, and an `Asset/Image` field within that, and I'm trying to add a `Position` field to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Position" field type is retired in Craft 3.

You can use this: http://plugins.supercooldesign.co.uk/plugin/button-box, or this https://github.com/Rias500/craft3-position-fieldtype instead, or just use plain old dropdowns.

Comment: The Rias version of [**Position Fieldtype**](https://github.com/Rias500/craft3-position-fieldtype) is the unofficial replacement for it. Button Box comes with a lot of other things you may not need.

Comment: Looks like Button Box isn't yet updated for Craft 3 — GitHub issue says it will be updated in Q2 of 2018:  https://github.com/supercool/buttonbox/issues/15  But Rias' Position FieldType is updated and in the new "Plugin Store". Thanks all!!

Comment: You are right, forgot to check Craft3 availability.